# Fraction field of $p$-adic power series ring

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, p-adic-number-theory, arithmetic-geometry

Let $L$ be a finite extension of $\mathbf{Q}_p$. Write $$\mathcal{O}_{\mathcal{E}} = \left\{ f = \sum_{k \in \mathbf{Z}} a_kT^k  \in \mathcal{O}_{L}[[T,T^{-1}]] \mid \lim_{k \to -\infty} a_k = 0\right\}$$

I read somewhere that the fraction field of this ring is $\mathcal{E} = \mathcal{O}_{\mathcal{E}}[1/p]$. Is that true ?

It seems weird to me because for example $p+T$ has inverse $\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k \dfrac{T^k}{p^{k+1}}$ which doesn't seem to be in $\mathcal{E}$ since it has arbitrarily big coefficients.

Comment: I think that the inverse of $p+T$ is $\sum_{n\geq 0}(-1)^n\frac{p^n}{T^{n+1}}$ that is in $O_E$

Comment: Ah ! But this is so weird then because there can only be one inverse in $L[[T,T^{-1}]]$ right ? Is "my" power series not an inverse ? Maybe i'm making a gross mistake ? Anyway thanks a lot for you answer. Do you know how to prove that $\mathcal{E}$ is indeed the fraction field of $\mathcal{O}_{\mathcal{E}} ?$.

Comment: In a commutative ring, an inverse of an element must belong to the ring. Here your element $\sum_{k\geq 0}(-1)^k\frac{T^k}{p^k}$ is not in $E$.

Comment: Of course but you can consider the ring $L[[T,T^{-1}]]$ and then both our power series are in it right ? so there must be a problem ? Although now that I think about it, it not clear what $L[[T,T^{-1}]]$ is ... In any case if you (or anyone) know why $\mathcal{E} = \text{Frac}(\mathcal{O}_\mathcal{E})$ I would love to see the proof.

Comment: C Hawkins, $L[[T,T^{-1}]]$ is not a ring. At least I don't see you could define a product there. What would be, for example, the square of $\sum_{k\in\Bbb{Z}}T^k$? That square has infinitely many terms of degree zero, namely $T^k\cdot T^{-k}=1$ for all $k$. The sum of countably infinitely many ones doesn't converge. That extra condition on the limit of coefficients is needed to make the products defined.

Comment: I can sort of see why the claim should be true. By truncating the series $a(T)$ by dropping low degree terms (i.e. negative degree terms) up to the first term of size $p^{-1}$, and then applying [Weierstrass preparation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_preparation_theorem) you get a kind of an "inverse" $u_n(T)$ such that all the high degree terms from some point on are tiny. Letting $n\to\infty$ I think (?) you get $u(T)=\lim_{n\to\infty}u_n(T)$ such that $u(T)a(T)$ has a maximum degree term. Whatever you then have left also has an inverse in your ring.

Comment: But there are so many fuzzy steps and potential pitfalls that I will wait on the sidelines for now. We have users who are quite knowledgable in this area, so I'm optimistic about somebody capable of answering showing up.

Comment: Thanks you very much Jyrki I will try to implement your idea. I was thinking of defining $L[[T,T^{-1}]]$ by $L[[X,Y]]/(XY-1)$ but indeed your can't represent every element as a sum $\sum_{k\in \mathbf{Z}} a_kT^k$.

Comment: So I have tried to implement what you said but I have a problem. How do you prove that any polynomial $P \in \mathcal{O}_L[T]$ which at least one invertible coefficient is invertible in $\mathcal{O}_\mathcal{E}$ ? For example I haven't been able to compute by hand the inverse of $p +T +pT^2$.

Comment: Ah of course it is easy to inverse $p + T + pT^2$ by hand. Still have to think about the case of a general polynomial though.

Comment: C Hawkins, do you think the following argument for the case $L=\bf{Q}_p$ works and generalizes? Let $f$ be an element of your ring. Multiply it by a power of $p$ to ensure that all coefficients are p-adic integers and at least one is a unit. Reducing that series modulo $p$ then gives a one-sided series in $S=\Bbb{F}_p[[T]][T^{-1}]$ with a non-zero lowest degree term. That series is invertible in $S$. Multiply the original series with a "lift" of that inverse gives a series with a single unit coefficient at degree zero. Invert that with the formula for a geometric series.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ring $\mathcal{O}_{\mathcal{E}}$ is equipped with the Gauss norm :
$$\|  \sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} a_n T^n \| = \max_{n \in \mathbb{Z}}(|a_n|),$$
which is multiplicative.

**Lemma 1:** The ring is complete for this norm.

> Proof: Let $f_s(T) = \sum_{n} a_n^{(s)} T^n$ with $s \geq 0$ be a sequence such that $\|f_s(T)\| \xrightarrow{s\to \infty} 0$. For each $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ the series $\sum_{s \geq 0} a_n^{(s)}$ converges to some $b_n$. The power series $g(T) = \sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} b_n T^n$ is in the ring for the following reason : let $\varepsilon >0$, and $S>0$ such that $|a_n^{(s)}| \leq \varepsilon$ for all $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $s \geq S$. Choose $N$ such that $|a_n^{(s)}| \leq \varepsilon$ for all $s \leq S$ and $n \leq N$. Then $|b_n| \leq \varepsilon$ for all $n \leq N$. The series $\sum_{s\geq 0} f_s(T)$ converges to $g(T)$ which proves that the ring is complete.

**Lemma 2:** If $f(T)= \sum_{n} a_n^{(s)} T^n$ is such that $\|f(T)\| =1$, then $f$ is invertible.

> Proof: Denote $n_0$ the least integer $n$ such that $|a_n|=1$. Write $f(T)=g(T)+h(T)$ where $g(T) = \sum_{n < n_0} a_nT^n$ and $h(T) = \sum_{n \geq n_0} a_nT^n$. Then $\|g(T)\| <1$ and $h(T)$ is invertible, and since the ring is complete it is well known that their sum is invertible.

With Lemma 2 it is easy to conclude that the ring $\mathcal{O}_{\mathcal{E}}$ is a DVR with maximal ideal generated by $\pi_L$, a uniformizer of $L$, hence its quotient field is $\mathcal{O}_{\mathcal{E}}[1/\pi_L]$ which is the same as $\mathcal{O}_{\mathcal{E}}[1/p]$.

---

**Note :** Jyrki Lahtonen's arguments works (once you have proven that geometric series converge) and generalizes to $L$ by replacing $p$ by a uniformizer of $L$ and $\mathbb{F}_p$ by the residue field of $L$.

Comment: Nice and simple! Thanks.

Comment: Sorry for not answering earlier, I didn't check the site. Thank you and Jyrki very much !

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen In the proof of lemma 2, is it correct that the sum of an invertible element and an element of norm strictly less than $1$ is invertible? Thanks!