# norm of invertible element in Banach ring

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, p-adic-number-theory, banach-algebras, arithmetic-geometry

Let $A$ be a commutative ring with a norm $∥·∥\geq0$ such that $∥ab∥\leq ∥a∥∥b∥$, $∥a+b∥\leq \text{max}\{∥a∥,∥b∥\}$, $∥1∥=1$ and $∥a∥=0$ if and only if $a=0$. We assume $A$ is complete for this norm.

If $∥x∥<1$ and $y$ is an invertible element, then how to prove $x+y$ is invertible?

This question is motivated by the proof of lemma 2 in the answer of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1859487/fraction-field-of-p-adic-power-series-ring/1869960#1869960), and user 10676 said that it is a well-known result, but I can't see this, because we can't deduce $∥y^{-1}∥<1$. Am I right?

Thanks!

Comment: If there is any invertible $x$ with $\|x\| < 1$, we have a counterexample with $y = -x$.  So the only way this could be true is if all invertible elements have norm $\ge 1$.

Comment: Note that in the other thread, $\|h\| = 1$ (since whatever coefficient makes $\|f\| = 1$ must be in $h$). As such $\|g + h\| > 0$. These additional facts are surely needed to obtain the guarantee of invertability.

Comment: @PaulSinclair  $∥h(T)∥=1$, but $\frac{∥g∥}{∥h∥}\leq ∥\frac{g}{h}∥$ and $g+h=h(\frac{g}{h}+1)$, so you can't deduce $∥\frac{g}{h}∥\leq 1$, so why is $g+h$ invertible?

Comment: @ Maybe $∥h^{-1}∥=1$ by analysing the inverse of $h$, so $∥gh^{-1}∥\leq ∥g∥∥h^{-1}∥\leq 1$?

Comment: @Sssss - I don't know the "well-known" result mentioned in the other thread (but I'm not an expert in this field, so that doesn't contradict the claim). Since Robert Israel noted that the result you gave is false, I looked at the other thread to see what other information was available. If I'd known how to show $g + h$ is invertible from this, I would have posted it as an answer, not a comment. As for the last comment, how do you know $h$ is invertible?

Comment: @PaulSinclair In the lemma 2 of the question which I referred to, $h$ is an inversible series, because the norm of the first term $a_{n_0}$ is $1$( notice the definition of the series $h$, so by basic $p$ adic number theory,  $a_{n_0}$ is invertible in $O_L$( coefficients ring of these series), and a Laurent series is invertible if it’s first coefficient is invertible, so $h$ is invertible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the answer you link to, there are additional conditions without which your statement does not necessarily hold, as Robert Israel notes in his comment.

Namely, what we have in the linked answer on top of what you write is that the norm is **multiplicative** (i.e. $\lvert \lvert ab \rvert \rvert = \lvert \lvert a \rvert \rvert \lvert \lvert b \rvert \rvert $), and that the invertible element you call $y$ **has norm $\lvert \lvert y \rvert \rvert = \mathbf{1}$**. Then it is indeed clear that

$\lvert \lvert xy^{-1} \rvert \rvert < 1$, hence

$1+xy^{-1}$ is invertible (geometric sum, ring complete), hence

$y+x = y(1+xy^{-1})$ is invertible.

Comment: In functional analysis, these inverses are typically called "Neumann sums". https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neumann_series

Comment: For the ring in the linked question, does the norm is multicative? I thought for a while to find a counterexample, but I failed...When we multiply two series, then  every coefficient of the product is a sum, so I don't think it is obvious that the norm is multicative.